# BERT get sentence embedding

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers

I am replicating code from [this page](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yFphU6PW9Uo6lmDly_ud9a6c4RCYlwdX). I have downloaded the BERT model to my local system and getting sentence embedding.

I have around 500,000 sentences for which I need sentence embedding and it is taking a lot of time.

1. Is there a way to expedite the process?
2. Would sending batches of sentences rather than one sentence at a time help?

.

```
#!pip install transformers
import torch
import transformers
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                  output_hidden_states = True, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
                                  )

# Put the model in "evaluation" mode, meaning feed-forward operation.
model.eval()

corpa=["i am a boy","i live in a city"]



storage=[]#list to store all embeddings

for text in corpa:
    # Add the special tokens.
    marked_text = "[CLS] " + text + " [SEP]"

    # Split the sentence into tokens.
    tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(marked_text)

    # Map the token strings to their vocabulary indeces.
    indexed_tokens = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenized_text)

    segments_ids = [1] * len(tokenized_text)

    tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens])
    segments_tensors = torch.tensor([segments_ids])

    # Run the text through BERT, and collect all of the hidden states produced
    # from all 12 layers. 
    with torch.no_grad():

        outputs = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)

        # Evaluating the model will return a different number of objects based on 
        # how it's  configured in the `from_pretrained` call earlier. In this case, 
        # becase we set `output_hidden_states = True`, the third item will be the 
        # hidden states from all layers. See the documentation for more details:
        # https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertmodel
        hidden_states = outputs[2]


    # `hidden_states` has shape [13 x 1 x 22 x 768]

    # `token_vecs` is a tensor with shape [22 x 768]
    token_vecs = hidden_states[-2][0]

    # Calculate the average of all 22 token vectors.
    sentence_embedding = torch.mean(token_vecs, dim=0)

    storage.append((text,sentence_embedding))
```

######update 1

I modified my code based upon the answer provided. It is not doing full batch processing

```
#!pip install transformers
import torch
import transformers
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                  output_hidden_states = True, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
                                  )

# Put the model in "evaluation" mode, meaning feed-forward operation.
model.eval()

batch_sentences = ["Hello I'm a single sentence",
                    "And another sentence",
                    "And the very very last one"]
encoded_inputs = tokenizer(batch_sentences)


storage=[]#list to store all embeddings
for i,text in enumerate(encoded_inputs['input_ids']):
    
    tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([encoded_inputs['input_ids'][i]])
    segments_tensors = torch.tensor([encoded_inputs['attention_mask'][i]])
    print (tokens_tensor)
    print (segments_tensors)

    # Run the text through BERT, and collect all of the hidden states produced
    # from all 12 layers. 
    with torch.no_grad():

        outputs = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)

        # Evaluating the model will return a different number of objects based on 
        # how it's  configured in the `from_pretrained` call earlier. In this case, 
        # becase we set `output_hidden_states = True`, the third item will be the 
        # hidden states from all layers. See the documentation for more details:
        # https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertmodel
        hidden_states = outputs[2]


    # `hidden_states` has shape [13 x 1 x 22 x 768]

    # `token_vecs` is a tensor with shape [22 x 768]
    token_vecs = hidden_states[-2][0]

    # Calculate the average of all 22 token vectors.
    sentence_embedding = torch.mean(token_vecs, dim=0)
    print (sentence_embedding[:10])
    storage.append((text,sentence_embedding))
```

I could update first 2 lines from the for loop to below. But they work only if all sentences have same length after tokenization

```
tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([encoded_inputs['input_ids']])
segments_tensors = torch.tensor([encoded_inputs['attention_mask']])
```

moreover in that case `outputs = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)`  fails.

How could I fully perform batch processing in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your original question: there is not much you can do. BERT is pretty computationally demanding algorithm. Your best shot is to use `BertTokenizerFast` instead of the regular `BertTokenizer`. The "fast" version is much more efficient and you will see the difference for large amounts of text.

Saying that, I have to warn you that averaging BERT word embeddings  does not create good embeddings for the sentence. See [this](https://medium.com/dair-ai/tl-dr-sentencebert-8dec326daf4e) post. From your questions I assume you want to do some kind of [semantic similarity](https://www.sbert.net/examples/applications/semantic-search/README.html) search. Try using one of those [open-sourced models](https://www.sbert.net/docs/pretrained_models.html).

Comment: is there a way to finetune sentence-bert models on my data?

Comment: yes you can fine-tune, all you need are relevant sentence pairs, take a look at the training utilities from the sentence-transformers library, the most performant approach is using [multiple negatives ranking loss](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/losses.html#multiplenegativesrankingloss) on NLI data, I'd give that a go

Answer (score 13):

One of the easiest methods which can accelerate your workflow is batch data processing. In the current implementation, you are feeding ONLY one sentence at each iteration but there is a capability to use batched data!

Now if you are willing to implement this part yourself I highly recommend using `tokenizer` in this way to prepare your data.

```
batch_sentences = ["Hello I'm a single sentence",
                    "And another sentence",
                    "And the very very last one"]
encoded_inputs = tokenizer(batch_sentences)
print(encoded_inputs)
{'input_ids': [[101, 8667, 146, 112, 182, 170, 1423, 5650, 102],
               [101, 1262, 1330, 5650, 102],
               [101, 1262, 1103, 1304, 1304, 1314, 1141, 102]],
 'token_type_ids': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 'attention_mask': [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]}
```

But there is a simpler approach, using `FeatureExtractionPipeline` with comprehensive [documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v3.0.2/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.FeatureExtractionPipeline)! This would look like this:

```
from transformers import pipeline

feature_extraction = pipeline('feature-extraction', model="distilroberta-base", tokenizer="distilroberta-base")
features = feature_extraction(["Hello I'm a single sentence",
                               "And another sentence",
                               "And the very very last one"])
```

**UPDATE1**
In fact, you changed your code slightly but you're passing samples one at a time yet, not in the batch form. If we want to stick to your implementation batch processing would be something like this:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                  output_hidden_states = True, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
                                  )
model.eval()
sentences = [ 
              "Hello I'm a single sentence",
              "And another sentence",
              "And the very very last one",
              "Hello I'm a single sentence",
              "And another sentence",
              "And the very very last one",
              "Hello I'm a single sentence",
              "And another sentence",
              "And the very very last one",
            ]
batch_size = 4  
for idx in range(0, len(sentences), batch_size):
    batch = sentences[idx : min(len(sentences), idx+batch_size)]
    
    # encoded = tokenizer(batch)
    encoded = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(batch,max_length=50, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
  
    encoded = {key:torch.LongTensor(value) for key, value in encoded.items()}
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        outputs = model(**encoded)
        
    
    print(outputs.last_hidden_state.size())
```

output:

```
torch.Size([4, 50, 768]) # batch_size * max_length * hidden dim
torch.Size([4, 50, 768])
torch.Size([1, 50, 768])
```

**UPDATE2**

There are two questions about what has been mentioned about padding the batched-data to maximum length. One, is it able to distrubting the transformer model with irrelevant information? **NO**, because in the training phase the model has presented with variable-length input sentences in the batched form, and designers have introduced a specific parameter to guide the model on **WHERE** it should attention! Second, how can you get rid of this garbage data? Using the `attention mask` parameter you can perform the mean operation only on relevant data!

So the code would be changed to something like this:

```
for idx in range(0, len(sentences), batch_size):
    batch = sentences[idx : min(len(sentences), idx+batch_size)]
    
    # encoded = tokenizer(batch)
    encoded = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(batch,max_length=50, padding='max_length', truncation=True)
  
    encoded = {key:torch.LongTensor(value) for key, value in encoded.items()}
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        outputs = model(**encoded)
    lhs = outputs.last_hidden_state
    attention = encoded['attention_mask'].reshape((lhs.size()[0], lhs.size()[1], -1)).expand(-1, -1, 768)
    embeddings = torch.mul(lhs, attention)
    denominator = torch.count_nonzero(embeddings, dim=1)
    summation = torch.sum(embeddings, dim=1)
    mean_embeddings = torch.div(summation, denominator)
```

Comment: There is an important caveat to consider, though: When using pipelines (or generally batched inputs), the outputs will have the *length of your longest input sequence*. Especially when averaging, this means you also average over "irrelevant" tokens which should ideally be ignored! I find this not well documented in the pipelines, so it isn't obvious that this padding occurs at all...

Comment: I didn't know any of these, thank you! @dennlinger

Comment: Sorry for another update, but I dug a bit deeper (the code in the main repository did not give me a clear indication where it would be padded), and it seems that **this behavior changed with version 4.11**. In fact, now the model will process each sample individually, which will result in the original length being preserved (expected behavior in your answer).

Comment: @ meti: Your update faces exactly the problem mentioned by @dennlinger.

Comment: @cronoik did you try the last one?