# Huggingface giving pytorch index error on sentiment analysis task

Tags: python, pytorch, sentiment-analysis, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to run sentiment analysis on a dataset of millions of tweets on the server. I am calling a API prediction function that takes a list of 100 tweets and iterate over the test of each tweet to return the huggingface sentiment value, and writes that sentiment to a solr database. However, after the process of few hundred tweets, I get the below error, any suggestions?

API code:

```
from transformers import pipeline   

model = pipeline(task = 'sentiment-analysis',model="finiteautomata/bertweet-base-sentiment-analysis")

# huggingface sentiment analyser        
def huggingface_sent(sentence):
    text=preprocess(sentence)
    if (len(text)>0):
        predicted_dic = {'NEG': 'Negative','NEU':'Neutral', 'POS':'Positive'}
        return predicted_dic[model(text)[0]['label']]
    else:
        return 'Neutral'


def predict_list(tweets):
    print('Data Processing\n')
    predictions={}
    for t_id in tweets.keys():
        if(tweets[t_id]['language']=='en'):
            predictions[t_id] = huggingface_sent(str(tweets[t_id]['full_text']))
        else:
            predictions[t_id]='NoneEnglish'
            
    print('processed ', len(tweets.keys()))
    print('\n first element is ', predictions[t_id])
    return predictions




print('Running analyser ....\n')
```

Error log:

> Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum
> sequence length for this model (211 > 128). Running this sequence
> through the model will result in indexing errors [2021-11-01
> 12:24:20,649] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/predict [POST] Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 2447, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 1952, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 1821, in handle_user_exception
> reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise
> raise value   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 1950, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line
> 1936, in dispatch_request
> return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint   File "/mnt/raid1/diil/sentiment_api/analyser_main.py", line 11, in
> api_predict_list
> predictions = predict_list(tweets)   File "/mnt/raid1/diil/sentiment_api/analyser_core.py", line 84, in
> predict_list
> predictions[t_id] = huggingface_sent(str(tweets[t_id]['full_text']))   File
> "/mnt/raid1/diil/sentiment_api/analyser_core.py", line 70, in
> huggingface_sent
> if model(text):   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py",
> line 126, in **call**
> return super().**call**(*args, **kwargs)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py",
> line 915, in **call**
> return self.run_single(inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)   File
> "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py",
> line 172, in run_single
> return [super().run_single(inputs, preprocess_params, forward_params, postprocess_params)]   File
> "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py",
> line 922, in run_single
> model_outputs = self.forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)   File
> "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py",
> line 871, in forward
> model_outputs = self._forward(model_inputs, **forward_params)   File
> "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/text_classification.py",
> line 133, in _forward
> return self.model(**model_inputs)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1051, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py",
> line 1198, in forward
> outputs = self.roberta(   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1051, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py",
> line 841, in forward
> embedding_output = self.embeddings(   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1051, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/roberta/modeling_roberta.py",
> line 136, in forward
> position_embeddings = self.position_embeddings(position_ids)   File
> "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py",
> line 1051, in _call_impl
> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)   File "/myusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tousername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py",
> line 2043, in embedding
> return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse) IndexError: index out of range in
> selfusername/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py",
> line 2043, in embedding
> return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse) IndexError: index out of range in self

Comment: *Token indices sequence length is longer than the specified maximum sequence length for this mode* may mean that the sentence/text is too long?

Answer (score 3):

As @Quang Hoang mentioned in the comment, it seems the problem is due to the length of your input tweet. Fortunately, you are able to determine the behavior of the [tokenizer](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiZrJHJmPnzAhVT7rsIHdj7AEoQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhuggingface.co%2Ftransformers%2Fmain_classes%2Ftokenizer.html&usg=AOvVaw2f75TB9GqZmpf99_IdyjSt) in `pipeline` class and truncate longer tweets explicitly. In addition, it's possible to set any other argument for pipeline elements.

```
MODEL_CHECKPOINT = "finiteautomata/bertweet-base-sentiment-analysis"
ner_pipeline = pipeline(task="sentiment-analysis", tokenizer=(MODEL_CHECKPOINT, {'model_max_length': 128}), model="finiteautomata/bertweet-base-sentiment-analysis")
```

As a side note, I recommend using the approach presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69521616/8704180) answer to accelerate the entire process.

Comment: Thanks Meti, Any idea on how to use the GPU with huggingface sentiment analyser in order to accelerate the sentiment inference process?

Comment: Note that i am running it using gunicorn

Comment: I have served This using uWSGI + docker container + GPU support using argument  `device=0` when instantiation of pipeline @Youcef

Comment: Thanks meti. Can you provide the line code ?